# Open set of the cuspidal curve is not principal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, algebraic-curves, affine-schemes

I'm struggling with this problem:

> Let $k$ a field and $X=\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y]\big/(x^3-y^2)$ and $U=X\setminus\{(x-1,y-1)\}$. Show that $U$ is not a principal open set in $X$.

I tried to show that we can't find a polynomial in this ring with only $(1,1)$ as zero, but I found problems related to $k$ is *any* field with *any* characteristic and not necessarily algebraically closed. I tried also to use the same arguments in $k[t^2,t^3]$ but they lead nowhere.

Thanks in advance to those who can help me.

Comment: Well, $U$ *is* a principal open set when $k$ is of characteristic two or three: it's the nonvanishing locus of $x-1$ and $y-1$ in those cases, respectively.

Comment: @KReiser ok sorry, I understood, but there are other exceptions with char$k>0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over a field of positive characteristic, $U$ is a principal affine open. Over a field of characteristic zero, $U$ is not a principal affine open.

The reasoning comes from the ability to write down a function $f\in k[t^2,t^3]$ vanishing only at $t=1$: such a function must be a power of $(t-1)$, but written as a polynomial in $t^2$ and $t^3$. When the characteristic is zero, $(t-1)^n$ always has a term $\pm nt$ which is never zero and any polynomial with a nonzero $t$ term cannot be written as a polynomial in $t^2$ and $t^3$. When the characteristic is positive, $t^p$ can be written as a product of $t^2$ and $t^3$, so $t^p-1=(t-1)^p$ is a function vanishing only at $t=1$ and therefore showing that $U$ is a principal affine open subset.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried this argument but I wasn't convinced because if $k$ isn't algebraically closed, for example $k=\mathbb{R}$, there are polynomials like $t^3-1=(t^2+t+1)(t-1)$ vanishing only at $t=1$ but not powers of $(t-1)$... does this still work?

Comment: Yes! Remember that the vanishing locus of a function in an affine scheme is the set of prime ideals which contain the function. For instance, your function $t^3-1$ belongs to the prime ideal $(t^2+t+1)\cap\Bbb R[t^2,t^3]$ which is distinct from $(t-1)\cap\Bbb R[t^2,t^3]$, and therefore $V(t^3-1)\subset\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb R[t^2,t^3]$ is larger than the complement of $U$.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!